# Divide one column for 2 rows in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

I would like to divide one column with long text to 2 the same height and width row. It would be in case if text would be too long. Is It possible to divide one column with one Text for 2 rows in its half?

I couldn't make it, I have no idea.

Comment: Is it a Text o a TextField?

Comment: Text. Question has been edited.

Comment: I think the best way is to use the SubcomposeLayout

Answer (score 0):

use weight

```
    Column() {
        Row(
            Modifier.weight(1f).background(Blue)
        ){
            Text(text = "Weight = 1", color = Color.White)
        }
        Row(
            Modifier.weight(1f).background(Yellow)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Weight = 1")
        }

}
```

Comment: But I would like to add one Text field. It would just divide textfield if it is too long to fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `row` and set modifier `weight: 1f`:

```
Row {
        TextField(
            value = "Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test" +
                    " Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test ",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
        TextField(
            value = "Test Test Test Test Test Test TesTest Test Test Test " +
                    "Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test ",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
    }
```

and if you want to have the second TextField in the next line if it's breaking line, you can use FlowRow

https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout

Comment: But as I said, it has to be one Text, but just spliting on the half if text is longer

Comment: It’s a weird implementation, but you can do that with custom views

Answer (score 0):

check this out this can be accomplished by using box.

```
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            var size by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
            val height: @Composable () -> Dp = { with(LocalDensity.current) { size.height.toDp() } }
            Text(
                text = longText,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(.45F)
                    // if second text is larger than first text call it on second text
                    .onGloballyPositioned { size = it.size.toSize() },
                textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
            )
    
            Divider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(1.dp)
                    .height(height())
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                color = Color.Black
            )
    
            Text(
                text = longText,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                    .fillMaxWidth(.45F),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
            )
}
```

Comment: But I want to use one Text because my text is in one string

Comment: can't you divide it into two parts?